# Flutter: How to detect keyboard press Enter?

Tags: dart, flutter

`TextEditingController.addListener()` registers a callback for when the text changes. This seems to also be triggered by pressing the Enter button, opening/closing the keyboard (changing focus).

How do i register that it was the enter that was pressed so i can, for example, invoke an API?

The current way i achieve this is by listening on the `FocusNode` to detect focus change. Focus is removed from the `FocusNode` when pressing enter, and the keyboard closes. Is this the right way to do it?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

There is a [`onSubmitted`](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/material/TextField/onSubmitted.html) property which accepts a `ValueChanged` callback. `onSubmitted` is triggered once the user press done after editing.

Hope that helps!

Comment: Don't know how i could have missed that. It was right in front of me. Thanks! :-)