# In Flutter is there a command that can be captured when pressing the Return button on the keyboard?

Tags: flutter, dart

I want to write command when the user presses Return and the keyboard disappears in the Webview or other component that the keyboard is running on?

Comment: There is a relevant existing question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48731195/flutter-how-to-detect-keyboard-press-enter?rq=1

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are using a TextField for input, the following applies:

> The text field calls the onChanged callback whenever the user changes
>   the text in the field. If the user indicates that they are done typing
>   in the field (e.g., by pressing a button on the soft keyboard), the
>   text field calls the onSubmitted callback.

https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/TextField-class.html

You need to provide a function to be called like so:

```dart
//... Parent widget here
child: TextField(
  onSubmitted: (val){
    setState(() {
      // do something here
    });
  },
),
```